# Templates no longer showing in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom

I'm using Lightroom 5.7.1 and have begun to experiment with print layouts. This was working well, however now when I select a predefined layout it does not appear on my page.

I thought this was related to the layout style, but this behavior occurs in all 3 styles.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the preferences file was corrupted. Renaming preferences in AppData (on windows) allowed the templates to work correctly again.